# JavaScript errors in IE8 - expected ';' & 'position().left' is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, runtime-error

Can someone please help me,I can't finish with the website until this is done, is a suprise for my family :(

I got one error in IE8.This function is working perfectly on all browsers why does IE marks an error,I simply don´t get it, all I can see is that there is no way out until it's fixed :( Please help me, there must be a minor glitch causing the error that is clearly invisible...

These are the errors, I would appreciate if someone can help me. I'm getting confused with the script.

** error**

> Message: 'position().left' is null or not an object Line: 44 Char: 5
>   Code: 0

which is this Line 44 - which is located within the script:

> $magicLineTwo

this is the entire code of the script there's nothing more in this script, there are two sets for this marked as " example 1 and example 2 "and the second one is making the problem:

```
 $(function(){

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
        $mainNav = $("#example-one"),
        $mainNav2 = $("#example-two");

    /*
        EXAMPLE ONE
    */
    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });


    /*
        EXAMPLE TWO
    */
    $mainNav2.append("<li id='magic-line-two'></li>");

    var $magicLineTwo = $("#magic-line-two");

    $magicLineTwo
        .width($(".current_page_item_two").width())
        .height($mainNav2.height())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item_two a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $(".current_page_item_two a").position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLineTwo.width())
        .data("origColor", $(".current_page_item_two a").attr("rel"));

    $("#example-two li").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLineTwo.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth,
            backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel"),
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLineTwo.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLineTwo.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLineTwo.data("origWidth"),
            backgroundColor: $magicLineTwo.data("origColor")
        });    
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you allowing your family members to suffer through IE8?

Comment: Your fiddle has no element with the id example-two. I'm getting a completely different error.

Comment: Does your markup contain an element with the class `current_page_item_two`? I doubled up your markup and added `#example-two` and an li with `current_page_item_two` and it's working fine in IE8\Chrome.

Comment: which error are you getting? this is the same script as the one in fiddle, there is nothing more in this put all there is.Is supposed to be for the menu,I would like to keep the same affect.It's been weeks now :(

Comment: In your fiddle I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'height' of null` because `$mainNav2` does not exist on the DOM

Comment: Pointy, well because this website might bring hope to my family but in this pace I don't know when it will be finished :(

Comment: Kyle Muir, is the example two making the problem but what could be causing this :( it's working fine in Chrome, Mozilla, and IE8 but the error on the corner points it :(

Comment: what could be done to fix this, I've been looking for a solution for weeks and no luck, this is the only error I got and until this is sorted I can't finish this website. :( please help me, I would deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a lot wrong with this, so I won't go into extensive detail (e.g. multiple jQueries on one page, referenced elements not on the DOM, etc).

This works in IE8 on my machine, you can feel free to fix the offending styles yourself. There are no JS errors showing in Chrome or IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/ghAkB/15/embedded/result/

Here is the fixed JS:

```
$(function () {

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#example-one")
    /*
    EXAMPLE ONE
*/
    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function () {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
    }, function () {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/ghAkB/15/

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you removed the second example,so was this part of the script useless?Can you just mention if you can what was the worst thing in this that made this error? Now is functioning perfectly without this second example, you made an amazing job, trust me I deeply appreciate your time and your help, it's a huge relief!! Thank you so much!! You are the only person who managed to sort the code!! :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I ask something else as there are only a geniuses and this coding is one whole labyrinth....Do I need to replace these two codes

js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'

for a newer version, do I need to update two or one is universal for all the functions? Which version should I download and also will that affect a jquery functions I have?

Comment: Yes it was. It was pointing at a menu that you didn't have. If this helped you please mark it as the correct answer :) glad to have been of assistance.

Comment: You should only ever have one jQuery file on your page unless you have a very good reason to have more than one (e.g. a plugin requires an old version) as you'd then need to start worrying about `noConflict`. I would recommend grabbing the latest version, I believe it's 1.10.

Comment: where do I download the latest version of jquery ,also is it universal with the rest of the jquery functions? I do have a problem with white flash in IE8 between pages, is that normal? I will mark your answer "100% help" , you are a genius in this!!!

Comment: You can download the latest here: http://jquery.com/ or use it from a CDN by linking to an address similar to this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` the white flash is most probably because the javascript hasn't finished loading yet. Hard to say though.

Comment: It asks for 15 reputation to be able to mark your answer :( ,should I put on the question that you gave a perfect answer? I'm new in this,but the moment I earn some points I'll mark it,in the meantime on top of the question I can write.

Comment: @Dalia it's fine :) Don't worry about it. The points aren't that important to be perfectly honest ;)

Comment: the white flash is a problem :( too, you helped me with this last error that finally removed the error list in the browsers and the white flash is another question to sort out :( don't remember making websites being so hard,I left this 4 years ago so I'm coming back to it and it's so hard :(